# How do I view Javascript output on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I want to test javascript code acting on a html document, like returning the .classList of a certain html element. jsfiddle only outputs the html, but how do I see the results of javascript code?

Comment: Have you tried your browser's console? Try F12

Comment: `console.log(js_var_you_want_to_view)`

Comment: No, console.log does not work, I only see the html output.

Comment: select a different frame in the console's drop-down (says <top frame> by default). the top one has nothing but the one that executes code often has errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting the console.log in chrome, but here is a workaround:

*you must turn on jQuery on the left side of the screen*

put this in the HTML frame:

`<div class = "output"></div>`

put this in your JavaScript frame:

```
var sampleFunction = function(){
  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
  return arr;
}

var answer = sampleFunction();
$('.output').append(answer);
```

To modify this for your needs, just be sure to set up sampleFunction so that 'return' is returning the output you want to see in the Result frame.

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7qq/) here